# how to maintain a persistent connection between 2 web-services and establish a duplex connection

Tags: java, sockets, web-services, https, apache-commons-httpclient

Problem statement-

I have a requirement to make an out bound SSL connection from behind the firewall to the external cloud web-service and keep that connection open for duplex communication, for ease of understating I am breaking up this requirement in to 2 phase as below.

Phase 1 -

I have an agent which is installed and run behind the firewall of customer, and it will connect to external cloud web-service by opening connection at port 443.

I have tried 2 ways -

1- SSL socket client

```
public class SSLSocketClient {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        
        
        SSLSocketFactory factory =
            (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket socket =
            (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("mycloud.com", 443);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        
        socket.startHandshake();
        boolean isLive = true;
        

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                              new BufferedWriter(
                              new OutputStreamWriter(
                              socket.getOutputStream())));

        
        
        out.println("GET /some/orgs/myorg HTTP/1.1");
        out.println("Host: mycloud.com");
        out.println("Accept: application/json");
        out.println("X-Api-Key: knwysf24tzeatwk5dwnqa6xh");
              
      

        out.println();
        out.flush();

        /*
         * Make sure there were no surprises
         */
        if (out.checkError())
            System.out.println(
                "SSLSocketClient:  java.io.PrintWriter error");

        /* read response */
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                socket.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);

        in.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

in this approach after every request-response cycle, connection get closed, and for every new request I need to re-open connection again.

To avoid connection reopen problem I tried to use apache commons-httpclient library

2- Creating HTTP connection using apache commons-httpclient library

```
public class HttpClientTest {

private static int connectionTimeout = 1000;
private static int socketTimeout = 10000;
private static String host = "mycloud.com";
private static int port = 443;
static boolean  useExpectContinue = true;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static DefaultHttpClient configureClient() {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, useExpectContinue);
    HttpConnectionParams
            .setConnectionTimeout(params, connectionTimeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, socketTimeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(params, Boolean.TRUE);

    String protocol = "https";
    params.setParameter(ClientPNames.DEFAULT_HOST, new HttpHost(host,
            port, protocol));
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

    return client;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String args []) throws IOException {
    String uri = "/idbridge/orgs/cableco_rt";
    
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
    httpGet.setHeader("Host",host);
    httpGet.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
    httpGet.setHeader("X-Api-Key","knwysf24tzeatwk5dwnqa6xh");
    
    
    String uriOrg = "/idbridge/orgs";
    
    HttpGet httpGetOrg = new HttpGet(uriOrg);
    httpGetOrg.setHeader("Host",host);
    httpGetOrg.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
    httpGetOrg.setHeader("X-Api-Key","knwysf24tzeatwk5dwnqa6xh");
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    DefaultHttpClient client = configureClient();
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();
    
    System.out.println("Client connected to -> " + params.getParameter("http.default-host") +"\n ______________________________");

    System.out.println("Request - > " + httpGet.getURI()+"\n");
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse rsp = client.execute(httpGet);
    
    
    HttpEntity entity = rsp.getEntity();
    Header[] allHeaders = rsp.getAllHeaders();
    System.out.println("Response"
            + " :  "+EntityUtils.toString(entity,"UTF-8") +"\n______________________________");
    
    
    
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse rspOrg = client.execute(httpGetOrg);
    System.out.println("Request - > " + httpGetOrg.getURI()+"\n");

    HttpEntity entityOrg = rspOrg.getEntity();
  Header[] allHeadersOrg = rspOrg.getAllHeaders();
  System.out.println("Response"
        + " :  "+EntityUtils.toString(entityOrg,"UTF-8"));      
}
```

}

This resolve my problem of re-opening connection every time, it create DefaultHttpClient once and we can reuse it any number of times.

Phase 2 -

Phase 2 of my problem is to maintain that connection that means, my source web-service created a connection as above described method and that same connection should be used by the target web-service, if it will require to request something in future, need to create some kind of hook or callback to open 2 way communication or I would say a duplex communication.

To solve this tried to use AsyncClientHttpExchange

```
public class AsyncClientHttpExchange {
 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
           CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
             try {
                    httpclient.start();
                 HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9090/connect");
                    Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(request, null);
                    HttpResponse response = future.get();
                    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(),"UTF-8") );
                    System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
                    System.out.println("Shutting down");
                } finally {
                    httpclient.close();
                }
                System.out.println("Done");
            }
```

}

But again it wont solve my problem of callback/hook, I read [this](https://dzone.com/articles/rest-callbacks) article I actually need the same behaviour

> Calling back The server side takes the initiative after completing a
> job and transforms itself in a client making an HTTP request to the
> original client (which acts now like a server, of course). The
> protocol has to be shared (such as PUT or POST requests with a certain
> format).

I am expecting some code reference to implement this behaviour.

Edited - Use case -> Service S1 and CS2(Cloud), S1 is reside on premise and connecting to user source, S1 will fetch data from the user source and then it will send it to cloud service CS2(S1 can open port 443 and make out bond SSL connection with CS2), now latter point of time, if any user come for authentication at CS2 service it will call S1 on premise service to authenticate with user source, Note - S1 and user source both are behind firewall.S1 can open port 443 and make out bond SSL connection with CS2 >this is one way, how can I can connect on demand from CS2 to S1(behind the firewall)

Comment: You could always use a `WebSocket` for duplex communication. The connection is only closed through explicit calls from the participating parties.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more? this his new territory for me

Comment: I suggest you first take a look at what WebSocket is : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-web-socket-and-how-it-is-different-from-the-http/

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I am on it. what would you suggest if I want do using HTTP only not with web-socket?

Comment: HTTP is not meant to be a two-way communication protocol. I do not know your exact use case, but you would have to ping the service very often to check whether there are new data. With WebSocket, the connection stays alive and every time a message is there, it is directly transmitted.

Comment: @Renis1235
Use case- Service S1 and CS2(Cloud), S1 is reside on premise and connecting to user source, S1 will fetch data from the user source and then it will send it to cloud service CS2(S1 can open port 443 and make out bond SSL connection with CS2), now latter point of time, if any user come for authentication at CS2 service it will call S1 on premise service to authenticate with user source, Note - S1 and user source both are behind firewall.S1 can open port 443 and make out bond SSL connection with CS2 >this is one way, how can I can connect on demand from CS2 to S1(behind the firewall)